# How to insert PHP variable to Vue computed functions in Laravel blade?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I need to bind `$price_php` with price in this `Vue object`. We do not use templates and imported components in the project

```
<html >
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Laravel</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="example">
    <?php $price_php = 100 ?>

    <p>Price: "{{ $price_php }}"</p>
    <p v-bind:price="$price_php">Computed amount: "@{{ amount }}"</p>

  </div>
<script>
var vm = new Vue({
            el: '#example',
              data: {
                quantity: 10
              },
              // props: ['price'],
              computed: {
                amount: function () {
                  return price*this.quantity
                }
              }
            })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe something like this would work for you.

```
<script>
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#example',
            data: {
                quantity: 10,
                price: <?php echo $price_php; ?>,
            },
            // props: ['price'],
            computed: {
                amount: function () {
                    return this.price*this.quantity
                }
            }
        })
</script>
```

**Reference of Idea:** See "Rendering JSON" subheading on https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#displaying-data